# Views disappear when scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, textview

I have a ScrollView with RelativeLayouts inside that include TextViews. I can only see text that appears at first, but if I scroll hidden elements do not appear (I should see the rest of the text when I scroll but I see empty space). Sometimes It shows one line of text just at the end, but only that.

I tried viewport = true in ScrollView, I changed the hierarchy... but nothing.

Does anyone know how to solve this??? It's driving me crazy!

Thank you very much.

This is my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/future_background"
android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/color_scroll" > <!-- android:fillViewport="true" -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >  <!-- android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:alpha="0.8" -->

    <!--
    BRIEF DESCRIPTION 
    =========================
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearBriefDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog_white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/internalLinearImageSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/speakButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:alpha="100"
                android:background="@drawable/speakclaro2" />

            <utils.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPOI"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ImageViewContentDescription"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/internalLinearBrief"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/internalLinearImageSpeak"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/internalLinearImageSpeak"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabelViewBriefDesc"
                style="@style/future_text_shadows"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/BriefDesc"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvViewBriefDescItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--
    LARGE DESCRIPTION 
    =========================
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLargeDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearBriefDescription"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLabelViewLargeDesc"
            style="@style/future_text_shadows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/LargeDesc"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvViewLargeDescItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelViewLargeDesc"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--
    ADDRESS 
    =========================
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLargeDescription"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLabelViewAddress"
            style="@style/future_text_shadows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/Address"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvViewAddressItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelViewAddress"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--
    SCHEDULE
    =========================
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearSchedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearAddress"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLabelViewSchedule"
            style="@style/future_text_shadows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/Schedule"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvViewScheduleItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelViewSchedule"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--
    PRICE
    =========================
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearSchedule"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_dialog_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLabelViewPrice"
            style="@style/future_text_shadows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/Price"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvViewPriceItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelViewPrice"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml layout to your question.

Comment: check your first textview height is it fill_parent or wrap_content

Comment: Thank you! It seems it's all about alpha property in RelativeLayout. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!

As you can see in the previous post I commented these lines:
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:alpha="0.8"
and everything is working ok now.

It seems It is related with alpha property in RelativeLayout, I don't know the reason (may because of alpha property in first button).

Thank you very much Wakim and Meenal Sharma!!